# How to add jwt authentication to existing login page on django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

So I am learning how to use Django and DRF and I created a Login and Register page on Django.
[Login and Register user view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUaiH.png)
with their own html pages
But, I don't want to use the normal authentication in Django and want to use Jwt token to authenticate
I have already downloaded it and and can use api/token and api/token/refresh to get the access and refresh token but I cant seem to find a way to use it in my already built login and register page to authenticate

Answer (score 2):

first install Django Rest Framework:

```
pip install djangorestframework==3.14.0
```

### Add it to installed apps settings:

config/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        # ...
        "rest_framework",
]
```

To implement JWT auth in our project, we are going to make use of djangorestframework_simplejwt. Install it:

```
pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt==5.2.2
```

Then, tell DRF the authentication backend we want to use:

config/settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ),
}
```

### Here are a couple of setting variables for simple JWT that can be customized in the settings:

config/settings.py

```
from datetime import timedelta

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=15),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=14),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": None,
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
}
```

If ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS is set to True, a new refresh token will be returned along with the access token. And if BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION is set to True, refresh token submitted to the refresh view will be added to the blacklist. You need to add 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist' to the list of installed apps for the BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATIONsetting to work. so let's do that:

## config/settings.py

## Third-party apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist",
]
```

Finally, run the following command to apply the app's migrations:
py manage.py migrate
Now, we need to create access and refresh tokens when the user registers/login. In the next section, we will add serializer and views to accomplish this task.

User Registration and Login Endpoints
Create a file named serializers.py inside the users app and add the following:

## users/serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import CustomUser, Profile

class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class to serialize CustomUser model.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("id", "username", "email")

class UserRegisterationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
   # Serializer class to serialize registration requests and create a new user.
    

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("id", "username", "email", "password")
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Serializer class to authenticate users with email and password.
    """

    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect Credentials")

class ProfileSerializer(CustomUserSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class to serialize the user Profile model
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("bio",)

class ProfileAvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer class to serialize the avatar
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("avatar",)
```

Note that we have also created a serializer class for the profile.
Then in the views.py

## users/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView, RetrieveUpdateAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

from . import serializers
from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()

class UserRegisterationAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    An endpoint for the client to create a new User.
    """

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserRegisterationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        data = serializer.data
        data["tokens"] = {"refresh": str(token), "access": str(token.access_token)}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

class UserLoginAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    An endpoint to authenticate existing users using their email and password.
    """

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserLoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        serializer = serializers.CustomUserSerializer(user)
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        data = serializer.data
        data["tokens"] = {"refresh": str(token), "access": str(token.access_token)}
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class UserLogoutAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    """
    An endpoint to logout users.
    """

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            refresh_token = request.data["refresh"]
            token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
            token.blacklist()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_205_RESET_CONTENT)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class UserAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    Get, Update user information
    """

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.CustomUserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

class UserProfileAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    Get, Update user profile
    """

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.profile

class UserAvatarAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    Get, Update user avatar
    """

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProfileAvatarSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.profile
```

The above views are self-explanatory. Basically, the views for user authentication use the RefreshToken class of simple JWT to generate and send to the client refresh and access tokens. In addition, the logout view blacklists the refresh token. The other views are used to get or update a user and his/her profile.
Now, let's hook our views in the URLs.

Head over to config/urls.py and add the users app URLs:

## config/urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("", include("users.urls", namespace="users")),
]
```

Inside the users app, create a file named urls.py and add the endpoints as follows:

## users/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView

from users import views

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    path("register/", views.UserRegisterationAPIView.as_view(), name="create-user"),
    path("login/", views.UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name="login-user"),
    path("token/refresh/", TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token-refresh"),
    path("logout/", views.UserLogoutAPIView.as_view(), name="logout-user"),
    path("", views.UserAPIView.as_view(), name="user-info"),
    path("profile/", views.UserProfileAPIView.as_view(), name="user-profile"),
    path("profile/avatar/", views.UserAvatarAPIView.as_view(), name="user-avatar"),
]
```

Note that the token/refresh endpoint will be used to get a new access and refresh token.